# drop down menu show selected item when page refreshes in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

Is there a way to make it so that when a html drop down form is used and the page refreshes in django / python for the drop down menu to stay on the selected filter?  Here is my current form:

```
<form name="portfolio_filter" action="" method="get"> 
    <select class="orderby pull-right push-bottom" name="orderby" onChange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
            <option value="">Filter for Products</option>
            <option value="{% url 'products:portfolio_filtered' '-our_rating' %}">Best Match</option>
            <option value="{% url 'products:portfolio_filtered' '-created' %}">Newest</option>
            <option value="{% url 'products:portfolio_filtered' 'title' %}">Sort A-Z</option>
            <option value="{% url 'products:portfolio_filtered' '-title' %}">Sort Z-A</option>
            <option value="{% url 'products:portfolio_filtered' '-unit_price' %}">Price: Highest to Lowest</option>
            <option value="{% url 'products:portfolio_filtered' 'sale_price' %}">Price: Lowest to Highest</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

The form works good, and let's me get to product portfolio list page and filter it by title, rating, etc.  But each time I do it, the drop down defaults to the first item:

```
<option value="">Filter for Products</option>
```

I'd like for it to stay on the selected item.  So if I go to "rating" then it would show that first "rating" filter in the drop down when the page reloads. I believe the html is `<selected="selected">` or something to that equivalent, that I'm wondering if I would populate with Javascript or JQuery?  But Im' not sure how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Better to load the page via ajax in that way form remains the same only the other part will be reloaded.

Or

if page has to be reloaded then use django-sessions or django cache and set the session or cache key to your selected value before refreshing and retrieve it back and send it to front-end.

Comment: would you be able to give me a code example of how to do this using django-sessions?  I tried using render_to_string to return the html based on what filter is picked and attach the <selected="selected"> but I couldn't get it to work so far. Thanks.

Comment: Best option is to use jquery and not to reload entire page.        OR                                                                  say user selects a option from dropdown then send the value selected to server side using Onchange event  and ajax call passing value to backend. Once the value is sent back in controller use, cache or session variable. like request.session['selected_val'] = 'selected value', And retrieve it using request.session['selected_val'] after page refreshes.

Answer (score 0):

I did this using Django for the time being.  I made a Dict:

```
portfolio_filters = {'title': 'Sort A-Z',
                    '-our_rating': 'Best Match', 
                    '-created': 'Newest',
                    'sale_price': 'Price Lowest to Highest'}
```

Then fed that Dict into my Paginated view:

```
def portfolio_filtered(request, slug):

template_name = 'products/shop-full-width.html'
products_list = Product.objects.order_by(slug)
paginator = Paginator(products_list, 12)
ideas = Idea.objects.all()

try:
    page = int(request.GET.get('page', '1'))
except:
    page = 1

try:
    products = paginator.page(page)
except(EmptyPage, InvalidPage):
    products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render_to_response(template_name,
    {'ideas': ideas, 'products': products,
    'portfolio_filters': portfolio_filters, 'slug': slug},
    context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Then in my template, I used this For Loop / If statement:

```
<select class="orderby pull-right push-bottom" name="orderby" onChange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
        <option value="">Filter for Products</option>
        {% for k, v in portfolio_filters.items %}
            {% if k == slug %}
                <option value="{% url 'products:portfolio_filtered_two' %}/{{ k }}/" selected="selected">{{ v }}</option>
            {% else %}
                <option value="{% url 'products:portfolio_filtered_two' %}{{ k }}/">{{ v }}</option>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Here is my URL as well if that matters:

```
url(r'^portfolio/filtered/$', views.portfolio_filtered, name='portfolio_filtered_two'),
```